# Proper way to handle hierarchical global data changes

Tags: language-agnostic, theory

Let's say you parsed a data file to generate thousands of items and put them in a hierarchical/tree format. Think like html, json, or QStandardItemModel (for any Qt users). Each item could have it's own text, icon, data, etc. Now let's say you want to stylize those items depending on their own data AND their relation to the surrounding items.

For example, make a parent item red if there is a child item with the name 'pie', but only if the parent item has a sibling named 'cheese', and only if the parent item is 2 steps down from the root item. And so on...

Well I was able to create a recursive function for my use case that does exactly that (with lots more check types). I basically created a JSON document that contains parameters for all the possible valid scenarios. Then in my recursive function, I check if an item fits in of those parameters, and then check for other related items as defined in the JSON document. I do this for every item.

The issue arises when the user edits one of the items. If someone changes the name of an item, then how would I let EVERY other item know that a change was made and they MIGHT now fit as a valid scenario? I can't just check the JSON document again for that edited item because that edited item might **not** be required to fit a scenario IF the styling action doesn't edit one of the checked items. Also, if the edit breaks a scenario, how would it know to undo it's effect on other items?

I can't just recheck parent items, because for all I know it might now fit with a parent>parent>sibling>child>child>child item. (And potentially more)

My answer was to rescan the entire thing, every, single, time. The downsides to this are that many times the changes are inconsequential, and performance can be a problem when there are thousands of items and dozens of possible scenarios.

Which got me thinking, how does software like Visual Studio know when to highlight something after you made a change when the highlighting could be dependent on a variable that could be far away in another document? Is there a *proper* way to handle situations like this? Or is rescanning the whole thing the way to go?

Comment: Since the question is tagged as _theory_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming is an interesting read.

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks, I just gave it a read. I think it's a little different than my particular situation given that their example of reactive programming in an object oriented language (of which I'm working in, c++) they simply call a function to "react" to an action "mouse click."

Whereas my problem is that the function I'm calling to "react" to an action "item edited" is a huge function that could **potentially** affect any other item. Knowing more precisely which items are affected ahead of time would be a lifesaver, but I'm just wondering if a standard already exists.

Comment: My current plan is to just multithread the heck out of it and cancel the current update cycle if a new edit is made, and then start over. Eventually, the user will stop and the update will go all the way through. This works for me because the updates don't rely on the previous update finishing.